# Is there a term to designate the "complexity" of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers, terminology

The simplest way to explain my question is using an analogy:

When classifying integers as odd and even, we speak of **parity**.
Is there an equivalent term when speaking of the "**complexity**" of a number? i.e. whether it's real, purely imaginary, or complex.

The closest term I can think of is **phase**, where 0 and $\pi$ means real, $\pi/2$ and $-\pi/2$ means imaginary, and all other values between $\pi$ and $-\pi$ are general complex numbers. But that is more of an indirect relation.

I noticed [MATLAB uses the term complexity](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcomplexity.html) but I find it weak. Is there a more appropriate term? I want to add this kind of property in a library I'm writing and I'd like it to be as intuitive as possible for the next people that read the code.

Comment: What properties are you hoping to have with this "complexity" measurement?

Comment: I don't think you can say a general complex number with imaginary component $i\pi$ is "real" – only that the resultant phase variable, $\phi$, itself is real (maybe that's what you were trying to say). Matlab's `mxComplexity`, as you've noted, is nothing more than a Boolean flag to indicate whether or not to allocate an imaginary component for a numeric value. I'm not quite clear on the distinction you're trying to make. Is it between real values (no imaginary component), general complex values (arbitrary real/imaginary components), and purely imaginary values (no real component)?

Comment: @horchler yes, the point was to categorize into 3 distinct, mutually exclusive groups: purely real, purely imaginary, general complex (i.e. non-zero real and imaginary parts). The question is more out of curiosity. I hope the analogy with *parity* helps to get my point across. I guess there is no such word, or else someone would have proposed it. Thanks